# Saleor custom url creation

Tags: python, django, saleor

I need to create a custom defined url like slug based on that some user data would be shown on the screen from the database but without authentication in saleor.

```
from saleor.graphql.utils import get_current_user, create_login_and_password_url
from saleor.core.utils.urlresolvers import reverse

urlpatterns = [
    path("my-custom-url/", my_custom_url, name="my-custom-url"),
]
```